# rows to columns snowflake

Tags: sql, pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aggregate-functions

i am struggling this one and any help will be appreciate. I am on Snowflake and i have a table with the following data

| Project | WBS_ID | Level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P.0051458 | P.0051458.01 | 2 |
| P.0051458 | P.0051458.02 | 2 |
| P.0051458 | P.0051458.03 | 2 |
| P.0051478 | P.0051478.01 | 2 |

I need this to be pivoted to something like this

| Project | Level_01 | Leve_02 | Leve_03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P.0051458 | P.0051458.01 | P.0051458.02 | P.0051458.03 |
| P.0051478 | P.0051478.01 |  |  |

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure that all `LEVEL`s in your sample data should be set to `2`? Shouldn't we have values from `1` to `3` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `LEVEL` column is what should be used to pivot (which does not match your sample data, but would make more sense), we can use conditional aggregation:

```
select project,
    max(case when level = 1 then wbs_id end) as level_1,
    max(case when level = 2 then wbs_id end) as level_2,
    max(case when level = 3 then wbs_id end) as level_3
from mytable
group by project
```

As opposed to vendor-specific `PIVOT` features, the syntax of conditional aggregation is supported in most databases - and it is also more flexible.